# How to globally treat all Eloquent timestamps as including timezone

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, php-carbon, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a Laravel application, and I just switched to `timestampTz` and `timestampsTz` in every single migration. As soon as I ran `php artisan migrate` I  immediately ran into ["Trailing data" issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16839) with Carbon due to the date format mismatch caused by the change.

I don't want to add the `$dateFormat` property to every model I create when I have no intention of ever using timezone-less timestamp columns. I also don't want to introduce a trait or make a new superclass that extends Eloquent's Model that I then need to add to every model I already have (and ones that I generate in the future).

Is there any way to avoid all this and just have every timestamp field be treated as if they all had timezones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done in Laravel 6 by creating a new Illuminate Grammar class and overriding the `getDateFormat` method, which is [used as a fallback](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.11.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L879-L887) if the `dateFormat` property is missing on a model.

Have a look inside `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars`. Your class will need to extend one of the vendor-specific grammar classes found here based on what database you connect to. For this example, I will be extending `PostgresGrammar`. Adjust `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` like so:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // ...

        $conn = DB::connection(DB::getDefaultConnection());
        $platform = $conn->getDoctrineConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
        $conn->setQueryGrammar(new class($platform->getDateTimeTzFormatString()) extends PostgresGrammar {
            protected $date_format;

            public function __construct(string $date_format)
            {
                $this->date_format = $date_format;
            }

            public function getDateFormat()
            {
                return $this->date_format;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This will replace the original query grammar with another that will let us take over the date format string. An anonymous class is used to avoid having to create a separate file for this small bit of functionality, but you may choose to move this to its own file for readability. The anonymous class is passed the value of `$platform->getDateTimeTzFormatString()` as the constructor's only argument, which is then stored for use by the `getDateFormat` method.

After this change, any trailing data errors should be gone for good. Just make sure to use `timestampTz` and `timestampsTz` in every migration going forward. 3rd-party libraries usually let you publish any migrations bundled with them, allowing you to adjust those as needed.